# Php remaking a table after data is added to the sql database

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to display data from my SQL database unto this page. When I run my code with only one data in the SQL database so if there is only one Wifi to fetch then everything looks normal and works well, but as soon as the user adds another wifi then the table is drawn again on top of the other table

A picture with only one wifi in my database

[image]

A picture with only two wifi in my database

[image]

Here is my wifi_page.php:

```
<?php 

require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Password FROM wifi";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $newWifi = "wifi_register_page.php";
        echo"
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><a href=". $newWifi .">+</a>
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td> ". $row["Name"]. "</td>
            <td>". $row["Password"]. "</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            </table>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$mysqli->close();

require_once 'footer.php' 

 ?>
```

If you need any more code or images just let me know in the comments. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need to fix the maximum width for table data and head.

Comment: I'd only use one table, and have multiple rows. `<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Password</td></tr>` outside the `while`.

Comment: @saddam thank you for answering but to what because in my CSS code it is already at 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the table and the header out of the while, otherwise it will create a new table for each row of your database.

```
<?php 

require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Password FROM wifi";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $newWifi = "wifi_register_page.php";
    echo "
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><a href=". $newWifi .">+</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    ";

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"
            <tr>
                <td> ". $row["Name"]. "</td>
                <td>". $row["Password"]. "</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            ";
    }

    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$mysqli->close();

require_once 'footer.php' 

 ?>
```